# SpriteKit gravity implementation

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

Here's what my scene.m looks like:

```
#import "ERGMyScene.h"
#import "ERGBackground.h"
#import "ERGPlayer.h"

@implementation ERGMyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    self.currentBackground = [ERGBackground generateNewBackground];
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
    [self addChild:self.currentBackground];}


ERGPlayer *player = [[ERGPlayer alloc] init];
player.position = CGPointMake(225, 100);
player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:10];
[self addChild:player];

return self;
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
SKAction *moveUp = [SKAction moveBy:CGVectorMake(0, 200) duration:0.3];
ERGPlayer *player = (ERGPlayer*) [self childNodeWithName:playerName];
[player runAction:moveUp];
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
CFTimeInterval timeSinceLast = currentTime - self.lastUpdateTimeInterval;
self.lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime;
if (timeSinceLast > 1) { // more than a second since last update
    timeSinceLast = 1.0 / 60.0; }
}
@end
```

I have gravity enabled in the ViewController(0,-5) and when the screen is tapped my image  does what it is suppose to do, go up 200 points and then come back down due to gravity. The first tap makes the character go up by 200, but each subsequent tap while the image is still in the air does not make the image go up by 200, which is what i would like for it to do. I presume this is because gravity is already acting on the image, causing it not to go up by 200. Is there a way to reset gravity for the image when a tap is made to have the image go up by a full 200?

Comment: Cannot find `[SKAction moveBy:duration:]` method in documentation. Try to use `[player.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, ...)]` instead

Comment: Is this what my new method should look like?                     -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
ERGPlayer *player = (ERGPlayer*) [self childNodeWithName:playerName];
[player.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 50)];
}                                                                                  It's working a lot better now and moves the way i want it to. Fluidly and affected by gravity but not to much. You've been a big help to me i'll be sure to ask my questions here from now on. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Use `applyImpulse` instead of `SKAction`:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ERGPlayer *player = (ERGPlayer*) [self childNodeWithName:playerName];
    [player.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, ...)]
}
```